# How can I check if url parameters exist with formik register form? Is there a ready exported function that does this from formik?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, http-post, formik, request-headers

I want to assign a value to one of the initial values (referrerId), based on whether URL parameters **exist** or not.
I have left out the other code which I believe is irrelevant for this question. When the form loads, I want the referrerId field to be prepopulated with id extracted from URL parameters.

```
<Form
  initialValues={{
    referrerId: // if there are no parameters set string "none" : referrer's id, which is extracted from params,
  }}
>

   <FormField 
      label="Referrer's Id"
      name="referrerId"
      placeholder="Referrer's Id"
      type="text"
   /> 

</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this possible is by using the URLSearchParams javascript interface.

```
const parameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

<Form
  initialValues={{
    referrerId: `${parameters.get('referrer-id')}`,
  }}
>

   <FormField 
      label="Referrer's Id"
      name="referrerId"
      placeholder="Referrer's Id"
      type="text"
   /> 

</Form>
```

and your url will look something like

```
https://mycoolwebsite.com/somepage?referrer-id=23221
```